# Splitting columns of 2D array into a separate 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I would like to send certain columns of a 2D array to another method as a 2D array. For example, I have the following array:

```
1 2 6 4
2 5 3 9
2 5 1 3
```

I would like to send lets say the middle 2 columns to a method as the 2D array:

```
2 6
5 3
5 1
```

How would I split this in a way that I could clarify the amount of columns being split and where I want the split to start and end. My understanding is that `System.arrayCopy()` would be an efficient way of performing this, however, I can only copy a 1D array with it.

Comment: Your question seems quite unclear to me. Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140861/java-pass-column-of-2d-array-as-1d-array

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
int[][] arr = new int[][]{
        {1, 2, 6, 4},
        {2, 5, 3, 9},
        {2, 5, 1, 3}
};

int startColumn = 1;
int endColumn = 2;
int[][] result = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(row -> IntStream.rangeClosed(startColumn, endColumn)
                .map(j -> row[j]).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(res));
```

Output: `[[2, 6], [5, 3], [5, 1]]`

It streams the 2D array and for each row, it builds a 1D array by picking the columns from `startColumn` to `endColumn` inclusive and collects every array in a 2D array.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to figure out, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a lesson in this.

It is easier to pick out a couple of rows of a two dimensional array.
So maybe *represent* columns as rows.

```
int[][] arr = {
        {1, 2, 2},
        {2, 5, 5},
        {6, 3, 1},
        {4, 9, 3}
};

int[][] sub = new int[] {
        Arrays.copyOf(arr[1], 3),
        Arrays.copyOf(arr[2], 3)
};

int[][] sharing = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, 3); // 3 exclusive.
```

The last `sharing` shares the rows (columns) with `arr`.

One could make one's matrix class.

> There is a story behind this. The Asian [*soroban*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soroban) is 90° rotated with respect to the Roman *abacus*. This makes it more readable IMHO, as reading numbers, and the *soroban* indeed is still a good pedagogical and useful tool.

Utilities: [`Arrays.copyOfRange​(T[],int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T%5B%5D,int,int)).

Answer (score 1):

To get a 2d sub-array from an existing 2d array - you can iterate over the rows of this array, and for each row, iterate over the *specified range* using the [`Arrays.stream(int[],int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D,int,int)) method:

```java
int[][] arr1 = {
        {1, 2, 6, 4},
        {2, 5, 3, 9},
        {2, 5, 1, 3}};
```

```java
int[][] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        // range from '1' inclusive to '3' exclusive
        .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row, 1, 3).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[2, 6]
[5, 3]
[5, 1]
```